# It would mean vs It means

Tags: subjunctives

Why there is the use of **would mean** instead of  **It means** in the following sentences?

***Context 1.***

> My son died saving his little brother-It would mean the world to us to have his bravery acknowledged

source: https://www.change.org/p/my-son-died-saving-his-little-brother-it-would-mean-the-world-to-us-to-have-his-bravery-acknowledged

**what is the meaning of this sentence?**

***context 2.***

> A. What is the meaning of 'To Lie' ?
>
> B. It **would mean** to say false things.

Is it the conditional or hypothetical use of 'would' ? please make it clear to me, what kind of use of **would** it is ?

Answer (score 1):

In **context 2**, I feel like the use of "It would mean" is incorrect, or at the very least, awkward. It would be much clearer and more typical to say:

> A. What is the meaning of "to lie"?
>
> B. It means to say false things.

In **context 1**, I disagree with you assessment and feel the word, "would", is being used in the conditional sense. Whether or not the speaker is affected is conditional on whether or not the son's bravery is acknowledged.

Another way of saying the same sentence in a more mechanical way would be:

> My son died saving his little brother. If his bravery were acknowledged, it would mean the world to us. If his bravery were not acknowledged, we would continue as we are (comparatively less satisfied).

Comment: What is the meaning of first sentence in context 1 ?

Comment: It means that the speaker's son died in the process of saving the son's little brother.

Comment: I'm currently unable to edit my previous comment so I'll add on here.

Comment: For example: Bill is drowning in the lake. Sarah jumps into the lake and saves Bill, but Sarah drowns instead.

Comment: What will you add here?

Comment: Then we can say, that "Sarah died saving Bill". (I hate how the enter key submits a comment).

Comment: I don't understand what ''The world to us" means.

Comment: What is the meaning of "The world to us" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48582/discussion-between-mattliu-and-yubraj-sharma).

Comment: "The world to us"= meaningfull or important